# JavaScript/jQuery: Clearing data after an API call

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, onclick, reset

I'm working on a simple project in JS that calls data from an API and returns to to a page. There is also a "Reset" button that should reset the API call back to baseline. I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the elements to reset. Usually I would do it with CSS classes, but this time around, I'll be constructing a larger assignment that will call APIs from user IDs. So I'd like to do this purely through JS/jQuery, and without using a form element.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Weather Vain</title>
</head>
<h1> Weather 4 Ever </h1>
<body class = "change">
  <p class="prompt">Type in a US city to get temperature data!</p>
  <form class="pure-form">
    <input type="text" class="pure-input-rounded">
    <button type="submit" class="pure-button">Search</button>
    <button type="submit" class="reset-button">Reset</button>
  </form>

  <p id="forecast"></p>

  <p class="date"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
  background-color: #5CBF94;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #FFF;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 100;
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
}

.prompt {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin-top: 4em;
}

form {
  color: #000;
  width: 290px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.date {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

JS

```
console.log("Script loaded")
"use strict";

(function() {
    $('.pure-button').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log("click noticed")
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + $('.pure-input-rounded').val() + ",US&appid=6549863730776a52fadf3fe935d5eecc&units=Imperial",
        type: "GET",
        success: function(data){
            var temp = data.main.temp
            var sky = data.weather[0].description
            $('#forecast').text("The current temperature in " + $('.pure-input-rounded').val() + " is " + temp + " degrees Fahrenheit. It is currently " + sky + "."  )

        }

    })
})

  (".reset-button").onclick.reset() //this is the part that I need to figure out.

})();
```

Link to CodePen: https://codepen.io/anfperez/pen/NJzPoE

Can anyone give me any pointers?

Comment: Call reset? `$("form")[0].reset()` Or use a reset button `type="reset"`

Comment: you will better use `$('.pure-form').submit(function(e) {`, see my answer following

Comment: And `$('.pure-form').on('reset', function(e) {`  to clear other parts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to remove the input value, you can in Jquery use the [`.val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function and give it a parameter of `''`.

Also, for performance, it is an better practice to store the Jquery elements in variables so you do not have to use Jquery to find them each time you do an action (like clicking)

```js
console.log("Script loaded")
"use strict";

(function() {
  var $inputElement = $('.pure-input-rounded');
  var $forecastElement = $('#forecast');

  $('.pure-button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log("click noticed")
    $.ajax({
      // var city = $('.pure-input-rounded').val()
      url: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + $inputElement.val() + ",US&appid=6549863730776a52fadf3fe935d5eecc&units=Imperial",
      type: "GET",
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data)
        var temp = data.main.temp
        var sky = data.weather[0].description
        $forecastElement.text("The current temperature in " + $('.pure-input-rounded').val() + " is " + temp + " degrees Fahrenheit. It is currently " + sky + ".")

      }

    })
  })

  $(".reset-button").click(function() {
    $inputElement.val('');
  })

})();
```

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: #5CBF94;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #FFF;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 100;
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
}

.prompt {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin-top: 4em;
}

form {
  color: #000;
  width: 290px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.date {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Weather Vain</title>
</head>
<h1> Weather 4 Ever </h1>

<body class="change">
  <p class="prompt">Type in a US city to get temperature data!</p>
  <form class="pure-form" onsubmit="event.preventDefault();">
    <input type="text" class="pure-input-rounded">
    <button type="submit" class="pure-button">Search</button>
    <button type="button" class="reset-button">Reset</button>
  </form>

  <p id="forecast"></p>

  <p class="date"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**No need to code anything.**

You use a form, so you just have to use a reset Button.

This is a basic HTML 1 feature:

`<button type="reset" class="pure-button">Reset</button>`

```js
(function() {

$('.pure-form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log("click noticed")
 $.ajax({
  // var city = $('.pure-input-rounded').val()
  url: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + $('.pure-input-rounded').val() + ",US&appid=6549863730776a52fadf3fe935d5eecc&units=Imperial",
  type: "GET",
  success: function(data){
   console.log(data)

      $('#forecast').text(`The current temperature in ${data.name} is ${data.main.temp} degrees Fahrenheit. It is currently ${data.weather[0].description}`)
  }

 })
})

$('.pure-form').on('reset', function(e) {
  $('#forecast').text('');
})

})();

// this is useless => (".reset-button").onclick("reset")
```

```css
html, body {
  background-color: #5CBF94;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #FFF;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 100;
  width: 100%;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
}
.prompt {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin-top: 4em;
}
form {
  color: #000;
  width: 290px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.date {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
img {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

input { background-color: #FFF }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@1.0.0/build/pure-min.css" integrity="sha384-nn4HPE8lTHyVtfCBi5yW9d20FjT8BJwUXyWZT9InLYax14RDjBj46LmSztkmNP9w" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1> Weather 4 Ever </h1>
<p class="prompt">Type in a US city to get temperature data!</p>
<form class="pure-form">
  <fieldset>
    <input id="input-city" type="text" class="pure-input-rounded"   placeholder="Enter city name here..." /> 

  </fieldset>
  <button type="submit" class="pure-button">Search</button>
  <button type="reset" class="pure-button">Reset</button>
</form>

<p id="forecast"></p>
```